# Apache 2.4.6 redirect some pages to new domain, some pages served from original server

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2.4

I have followed every link I can find on google on how to do this

I am in the process of moving my domain, I have a couple of links out there that I need to redirect, some can stay on the server hosting the site.

This is a basic html/php site nothing else.

Old Domain - http://olddomain.com
New Domain - http://newdomain.com

When a user hits http://olddomain.com/ I want that page to be index.html from the server

When a user hits http://olddomain.com/contact-us.html I want that page to be contact-us.html from the server

When a user hits olddomain.com/service.html  I want that page redirect to http://newdomain.com

Sorry for not putting out more examples of what I have tried

Below is my httpd.conf I am not using htaccess files

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
```

#First Attempt

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName olddomain.com
    ServerAlias www.olddomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/olddomain
    DirectoryIndex index.html

#Thinking here is if the URL does not contain index.html or contact-us.html then redirect to         http://newdomain.com
#This one just redirects everything

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule !index\.html$ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
    RewriteRule !contact-us\.html$ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

#Second Attempt

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName olddomain.com
    ServerAlias www.olddomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/olddomain
    DirectoryIndex index.html

#Thinking here is if the URL does not contain index.html or contact-us.html then redirect to         http://newdomain.com
#This one just gets ignored

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "! /index.html" [OR]
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "! /contact-us.html" [OR]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: "redirect all pages" / "a couple of links out there that I need to redirect" - "all" or "a couple"? Or is "all" only "a couple"?? Your "Second Attempt" also looks like it would redirect _everything_?! (You should never test with 301s) But you are redirecting to `https` in the second and `http` in the first? And `olddomain.com` is HTTP only?

Comment: @MrWhite From the site olddomain.com, there are links in the page, services, contact, etc, I need some of them (ie. services) to redirect to newdomain.com, however when a user hits olddomain.com (ie. olddomain.com\index.html) I want to original homepage and when they click contact (ie. olddomain.com\contact-us.php I want the original contact us page. if they click services, I want that to redirect to the newdomain.com page, Which I do not have control over. There are a couple other thinks throughout the oldomain.com I want to redirect but I figure if I can figure out 1 I can get the rest.